# How to use awk variable inside double quotes?

Tags: awk

I have the following shell variable defined:

```
memory_params="some memmory params"
class_path="some class path"
class_name="some class name"
```

Now, I use these bash variable inside awk

```
awk -v var1="${memory_params}" \
    -v var2="${class_path}" \
    -v var3="${class_name}" \
  '{ 
     cmd="java var1 -cp var2 var3";
     system(cmd);  
   }'
```

But, this doesn't take the values of `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` for obvious reason. How can awk variables be used inside double quotes?

Comment: `echo aaa | awk -v var="${memory_params}" '{print var}'` prints the content of $memory_params. Try to test your solution step by step to catch the error

Comment: @m47730 This works fine. Issue is to access the `var` inside double quotes like in the java command mentioned in the question.

Comment: Your question could be replaced by: "Using awk, how can I build a string using constant parts and variables. This question is not related to Bash at all.

Comment: Why do you want do this `awk` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

try following once and let me know if this helps. Use variables in `system` command directly rather than creating a variable and passing it to `system`.

```
awk -v var1="${memory_params}" \
    -v var2="${class_path}" \
    -v var3="${class_name}" \
  BEGIN'{ 
     system("java " var1 " -cp " var2 OFS var3);  
   }'
```

Remove that `BEGIN` in case you have any `Input_file` to be read.

Comment: How is it a hack? What kind of approach would you consider _more elegant_ ?

Comment: @JamesBrown Sorry to call it a hack. Deleted the comment. I was just curious if awk variables can be used inside double quotes at all.

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible. With right quoting you could use bash variables inside awk scripts but that would lead to a lot of quote escaping, unreadable code and it's potentially dangerous. `foo=bar; awk "BEGIN{print \"foo is $foo\"}"` Far from elegant, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have also come across same scenario,below command I used which resolved my issue.

**database_impala=test_db
awk  -v var="${database_impala}" '{ print var"."$0}'**